# disable menu based on value of a preference variable

Tags: eclipse-plugin, rcp

I have a menu item XYZ. I have a preference page MyPref which has a check box and a couple of text fields. When the check box in MyPref is check, I want menu XYZ to be enabled else it should be disabled. Is there a way to achieve this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the way certainly exist.

1). Create an entry in your `IPreferenceStore` - just get the class which extends `AbstractUIPlugin` and do the following:

```
IPreferenceStore store = IExtendAbstractUIPlugin.getDefault()
      .getPreferenceStore();
```

then store some value which will reflect your checkbox state:

```
preferenceStore.setValue("XYZMenuPreference", false); // if disabled
```

or

```
preferenceStore.setValue("XYZMenuPreference", true); // if enabled
```

2). Create a `Property Tester` extention to your plugin.xml:

```
<extension point="org.eclipse.core.expressions.propertyTesters">
  <propertyTester
     class="org.xyz.PropertyTester"
     id="org.xyz.PropertyTester"
     type="java.lang.Object"
     namespace="org.xyz"
     properties="XYZmenu">
  </propertyTester>
</extension>
```

3). When declaring your menu handler in `plugin.xml` you should add the following:

```
<handler
 class="your-menu-handler-class"
 commandId="your-command-id">
     <enabledWhen>
     <with variable="selection">                    
     <test property="org.xyz.XYZmenu" value="true" forcePluginActivation="true"/> 
     </with> 
     </enabledWhen>           
</handler>
```

4). Now you need a class "org.xyz.PropertyTester" (as defined in plugin.xml) which will extend the `org.eclipse.core.expressions.PropertyTester` and override method `test(<some args>)` where he must check the `property` value:

```
if (property.equals("XYZmenu"){
   IPreferenceStore store = IExtendAbstractUIPlugin.getDefault()
                    .getPreferenceStore();
   return store.getBoolean("XYZMenuPreference");
}
```

5). After that add a change listener to your checkbox and use it to re-evaluate a visibility of your menu item:

```
IEvaluationService service = (IEvaluationService) PlatformUI
   .getWorkbench().getService(IEvaluationService.class);
service.requestEvaluation("org.xyz.XYZmenu");
```

it will force the method `test()` from your `org.xyz.PropertyTester` class to be called and will enable your menu item if preference
"XYZMenuPreference" is set to `true`.

upd.

```
namespace - a unique id determining the name space the properties are added to
properties - a comma separated list of properties provided by this property tester
```

this is from [official eclipse tutorial](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/extension-points/org_eclipse_core_expressions_propertyTesters.html) so you can feel free to define any namespace and property name, but the you should use it like in point 5.

Comment: Thank you so much. In the sample code i am not able to get how to derive the values of namespace and property name should be. Can you please clarify

Comment: Thanks a lot @Alex. Exactly what I needed, works perfect.